# Recursion Function exceeds Time limit for Large Values

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

**Problem Description:**

Two arrays are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the arrays.
Given two arrays a and b, check whether they are similar.

```
int recursionGuard = 0;
bool solution(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != b[i])
        {
            if(recursionGuard == 0)
            {
                recursionGuard = 1;
                for (int j = i+1; j < b.size(); j++)
                {
                    vector<int> new_b = b;
                    vector<int> new_a = a;
                    iter_swap(new_b.begin() + i, new_b.begin() + j);  
                    new_a.erase(new_a.begin()+i);
                    new_b.erase(new_b.begin()+i);              
                    if(solution(new_a, new_b) == 1)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }else 
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I am using recursion to solve this problem and almost all but one test cases pass. The reason is exceeded time limit for larger values. Is there a way to somehow optimize the function?

Comment: What's the constraint and time limit?

Comment: I guess this a competitive programming question. I've been there. Normally you need to think wisely how to do your algorithm. A pure brute force algorithm almost never works

Comment: Not copying the vectors all the time, but instead working via references, would certainly go a long way to reduce the time this code takes

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the return type of the function `solution` is `bool`, so the `return` statements should return `true` or `false`. Similarly, `if(solution(new_a, new_b) == 1)` should be `if(solution(new_a, new_b))`, because the result of the function call is already boolean.

Comment: Why would you choose to use a recursive solution?  And why do you need to erase items from vectors to solve the problem?

Comment: Using [std::mismatch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) reduces this to a linear solution -- no need for recursion or erasing items from the vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You're brute-forcing this problem, and that always leads to pain - slow code, high memory consumption, you name it. Such algorithmic problems require a bit of creative thinking.

Let's look at your problem statement: See if two arrays can be made equal by swapping at most one pair of elements in one array.

**What does that entail?**

That situation can happen *only* if two arrays differ in exactly two places - if it's three or more, one swap isn't gonna be enough. So there's one shortcut for you: **if two arrays differ in three or more places, they cannot be made equal**. That "filter" alone will save your CPU a lot of computational effort.

Then, say our two arrays do differ in only two places. How can we check that one swap will make them identical? I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am new to C++ programming and wanted to give this problem a try with recursion, because I still struggle with it. I wanted to know if there is some way to optimize the use of recursions in general.

Comment: @JoelD'Souza it can be fun to use recursion to solve problems and to learn to use it, but this problem in particular isn't a good fit. There is nothing recursive about it: just two arrays that need to be linearly iterated upon.

Comment: @JoelD'Souza Don't start learning C++ with solving random problems, start with the language itself.